# add two layouts in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

i'm trying to put image besides the radio buttons but only one of them i can show, so how can i add image beside radio buttons in same page.

```
def SecondPage(self):
     layout = QGridLayout()

     rd1 = QRadioButton('r1')
     rd2 = QRadioButton('r2')
     rd3 = QRadioButton('r3')
     rd3.setChecked(True)



     vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
     labelImage = QLabel(self)
     pixmap = QPixmap('b.png')
     labelImage.setPixmap(pixmap)       
     vbox.addWidget(labelImage, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

     page.setLayout(layout)
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

if you do mean 'besides' as 'below'

```
def SecondPage(self):
     layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

     rd1 = QRadioButton('r1')
     labelImage = QLabel(self)
     pixmap = QPixmap('b.png')
     labelImage.setPixmap(pixmap)
     vbox = QVBoxLayout() 
     vbox.addWidget(rd1) 
     vbox.addWidget(labelImage, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
     layout.addLayout(vbox) 

     rd2 = QRadioButton('r2')
     pixmap = QPixmap('b.png')
     labelImage.setPixmap(pixmap)
     vbox = QVBoxLayout() 
     vbox.addWidget(rd2) 
     vbox.addWidget(labelImage, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
     layout.addLayout(vbox) 



     rd3 = QRadioButton('r3')
     rd3.setChecked(True)
     pixmap = QPixmap('b.png')
     labelImage.setPixmap(pixmap)
     vbox = QVBoxLayout() 
     vbox.addWidget(rd3) 
     vbox.addWidget(labelImage, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
     layout.addLayout(vbox) 


     self.second_page.setLayout(layout)
```

Comment: when i run your code i got 'function' object has no attribute 'setLayout'

Comment: you need to create it before fill in content. for example, `self.second_page = QWidget(); self.second_page.show()`

Comment: may you update you complete code? `self.second_page` should be a widget but not a function.

Comment: it works fine, but  i want radio buttons vertically not horizontally, thanks in advance

Comment: 3 buttons vertically and next to them one image which is "b.png"

Comment: `layout = QVBoxLayout(self)` `vbox = QHBoxLayout() ` replace all these to change direction

Comment: another question sir, how i can resize the image it's too big i want to make it smaller.